# Installing pyomo windows 10

Tags: python, pyomo

I want to install an energy optimization tool  [URBS](https://github.com/tum-ens/urbs)   which is written in python.

An installation procedure is written with it but summary of it is as under.

1. Install Anaconda
2. Install pyomo using `pip install pyomo`
3. Install GLPK (latest) and add its path

When I follow all this procedure and at the end use this command `python runme.py`

It work perfectly fine in Windows 7 but donot work in windows10
It gives error while using windows 10 as attached in the following image. [image: Picture Error].

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the output from the installation, which seems to be garfed somehow. There is no reason that the line "coopr.environ" should be called in this example, and _VarDataWithDomain is not imported in the latest Pyomo release (Pyomo 4.3.11377)

Comment: The problem is solved now.
On windows 7 code was perfectly fine with pyomo (latest)
I tried this code in on 3 Machines with windows 10 got same problem because pyomo4.3.11377 was not woorking in windows 10.

Even `pyomo --version` command was giving error. I uninstalled and reinstalled it several times with different techniques but error was same then I used a previous version using `pip install pyomo==4.3.11328` and it got solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyomo latest release which is `pyomo4.3.11377` is not working with windows 10.

I have tried an older version using `pip install pyomo==4.3.11328` and it solved all of my problems and I used an older version of **glpk4.57** with it to run the optimizations

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem with the wheel file that was uploaded to pypi. The issue was fixed as of Pyomo 4.3.11388.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing missing coopr module: **pip install Coopr**

More in this link,
https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/coopr/CooprInstallGuide.html

Comment: I tried this but it did not help. This problem was as I mentioned on above post.

`pyomo --version` command was also not able to execute.


I got the solution as I mentioned in my above answer.